# How can I find which jar file I need to add to my class path to reference a class

Tags: java, jar

There have been other references here to search jar files for list of classes. That is not the intent of my question.
I specifically want to know what are the typical tricks/tip to determine which external jar file I need to download and add as reference to my class path if my code needs to reference a certain 3rd party class for which I don't know to which jar file it belongs to.

Example could be org.apache.http.HttpEntity or any other class from a 3rd party?

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Just try to run/compile the code and it will tell you exactly what is missing. Also, a quick browse through the main class files will show you the major imports at the top of the class so you can knock out the majority of possible libraries/dependencies.

Comment: https://www.findjar.com/